How to troubleshoot “Process system isn't responding” on real device Android 12 241116
In the quest for stable Android, there are popups with text:
.
Process system isn't responding

with actions:
✕ Close app
 Wait

.

After the first occurrence since boot, occasional 20 s device slowness sometimes with the dialog repeated until reboot

The dialog generally restarts logcat so there are typically no logs available

After a bit of effort, I had the unrooted Android capturing logcat with O_SYNC open bit until the thing failed after 4 days

However, there are no clues in logcat, not even anything about the dialog being displayed

Statements on the Internet claims the dialog generally associated with failing hardware


1. What are the circumstances for Android to display “Process system isn't responding”?
What process shows the dialog?
Why is the slowness condition not in logcat?
2. Is it hardware malfunctioning or misbehaving software?
3. How can the root cause of “Process system isn't responding” be found?
. update:
The dialog is created by ActivityManager: Completed ANR of system
grep ANR 241116-095955-process-system-logcat.txt
…
2024-11-16 09:59:44.971002  1000  1761  2040
I WindowManager: ANR in gesture monitor owned by pid:1761.
Reason: PointerEventDispatcher0 (server) is not responding.
Waited 5002ms for MotionEvent
2024-11-16 09:59:49.624343  1000  1761  3294
E ActivityManager: ANR in system
2024-11-16 09:59:49.628863  1000  1761  3294
D ActivityManager: Completed ANR of system in 4626ms, latency 0ms
…
2024-11-16 09:59:55.412488  1000  1761  1874
I ActivityManager: Start proc 3404:com.android.systemui:screenshot/u0a228
for service
{com.android.systemui/com.android.systemui.screenshot.TakeScreenshotService}

This indicates a failed gesture event that started at 09:59:39.968700

1761 is a glue-process handling broadcasts and such

ps -fp1761
UID            PID  PPID C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
system        1761  1094 4 08:53 ?        04:20:47 system_server

The soft keyboard was shown for the browser omnibar 34.6 ms after this time:
2024-11-16 09:59:40.023154 10192  3025  3025
I GoogleInputMethodService:
GoogleInputMethodService.onFinishInput():3058

Most likely this is caused by the device having a cracked display
and the digitizer therefore not working reliably

if the digitizer fails to respond within 5 s, the dialog is shown

Finding System Instability in logcat
egrep '(FATAL EXCEPTION|WATCHDOG|DeadSystemException|ANR)' 241024-165843-07--logcat.txt

You are doing heavy work on the MainThread which might be the root cause of ANR, perform heavy and long running operations on background threads, keep UI thread free
